# Divi theme primary header menu center aligned

Tags: css, wordpress

[image]I'm using divi theme for a wordpress site. The top primary menu is right aligned by default. How can I customize it to have it center aligned?

Code :

@media only screen and ( min-width: 981px ) {

```
/* Vertically center the top navigation */
#et-top-navigation { vertical-align: middle; float:none !important;}
.container { display:table; }

/* Center align the contents of the top navigation area */
#et-top-navigation { text-align:center; }
#et-top-navigation > * { text-align:left; }

#top-menu-nav, #et_top_search { float:none !important; display:inline-block !important}
#et_top_search { vertical-align: top !important; margin-top:3px }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In the future I would suggest asking the question better since this one provides too little information to help solve the problem. Fortunately, I now Divi well. Here is your solution.

In your stylesheet:

```
#et-top-navigation {
    float: none; 
    text-align: center; 
}

nav.fullwidth-menu-nav {
   float: none;
}
```

Comment: @danwebb1 Also, she wants social media icons to be right aligned. Is it possible?
Your above solution will make the main menu center aligned.

Comment: So basically, the primary menu in divi includes the logo, the menu items and the social media icons. I want the logo to be aligned on the left, menu items in the center and the social media icons to the left.

Comment: Code :
@media only screen and ( min-width: 981px ) { 

 /* Vertically center the top navigation */
 #et-top-navigation { vertical-align: middle; float:none !important;}
 .container { display:table; }

 /* Center align the contents of the top navigation area */
 #et-top-navigation { text-align:center; }
 #et-top-navigation > * { text-align:left; }

 #top-menu-nav, #et_top_search { float:none !important; display:inline-block !important}
 #et_top_search { vertical-align: top !important; margin-top:3px }
 

 
}